# ¿Cómo llamar? / ¿Usar Procedimientos almacenados en MVC en Leaf PHP?

Tags: php, laravel, leaf

Tengo una duda, estoy aprendiendo Leaf PHP (3.0). Estoy haciendo un proyecto MVC (para hacer una API). Mi duda radica en que no se como puedo llamar un procedimiento almacenado en dicho Framework. A continuación, pongo el código de "routes", "models" y "controllers"

"routes"

```js
<?php

app()->get("/", function () {
    response()->json(["message" => "Usando Leaf para API REST"]);
});

//--Consulta todos los registros (Verbo GET)
app()->get("/Login", 'LoginController@index');  
//--Consulta todos los registros x ID (Verbo GET)
app()->get("/Login/{id}", 'LoginController@consultar');
//--Inserta registros (Verbo POST)
app()->post("/Login", 'LoginController@agregar'); 
//--Actualiza registros (Verbo PUT)
app()->put("/Login/{Id}", 'LoginController@actualizar'); 
//--Borra registros (Verbo DELETE)
app()->delete("/Login", 'LoginController@borrar');
```

controllers:

```js
<?php
      namespace App\Controllers;
      use App\Models\Login;//<--nombre de la clase donde está la tabla que se usa
       

      class LoginController extends Controller{

              public function index(){
                 $datosLogin=Login::all(); //Trae los registros de la tabla como un "select *"
                 response()->json($datosLogin); 
               } 

              public function consultar($id){ //--Encontrar un usuario por ID
                 $datosLogin=Login::find($id);  
                 response()->json($datosLogin); 
               }

             public function agregar(){  //--Insertar un usario
                    $pruebamvc = new Login; //--Prepara un nuevo registro en la tabla
                    //echo app()->request()->get('nombre'); 
                    $pruebamvc->nombre=app()->request()->get('nombre');
                    $pruebamvc->apellido=app()->request()->get('apellido');
                    $pruebamvc->Id_personal=app()->request()->get('Id_personal'); 
                    $pruebamvc->save();//--Esta es la instrucción equivalente a "Insert into... etc
                    response()->json(["message" => "Registro insertado"]); 
               }

             public function actualizar($Id){  //--actualiza   
                 //$Id=app()->request()->get('Id'); 
                 $nombre=app()->request()->get('nombre'); 
                 $apellido=app()->request()->get('apellido');
                 $Id_personal=app()->request()->get('Id_personal'); 
                 
                 if ($Id==null or $Id=="" or $Id=="0" or 
                       $nombre==null or $nombre=="" or $apellido==null or 
                       $apellido=="" or  $Id_personal==null or $Id_personal=="0" or 
                       $Id_personal=="Object" or $Id_personal==""){
                       response()->json(["message" => "Registro no actualizado. Alguno de los datos están nulos."]);
                 }
                 else{
                      $pruebamvc=Login::findOrFail($Id);
                      //$pruebamvc=Login::find($Id);
                      //$pruebamvc->Id=($Id!="")?$Id:$pruebamvc->Id;
                      //$pruebamvc->nombre=($nombre!="")?$nombre:$pruebamvc->nombre;
                      //$pruebamvc->apellido=($apellido!="")?$apellido:$pruebamvc->apellido;
                      //$pruebamvc->Id_personal=($Id_personal!="")?$Id_personal:$pruebamvc->Id_personal; 
                      $pruebamvc->nombre=app()->request()->get('nombre');
                      $pruebamvc->apellido=app()->request()->get('apellido');
                      $pruebamvc->Id_personal=app()->request()->get('Id_personal');  
                      $pruebamvc->update();//--Esta es la instrucción equivalente a "Update... etc
                      response()->json(["message" => "Registro actualizado"]);
                      //response()->json($pruebamvc);
                 }  
               }

             public function borrar($id){ //--borra un usuario por ID
                 $datosLogin=Login::destroy($id);  
                 response()->json($datosLogin); 
                 response()->json(["message" => "Registro eliminado"]); 
               }

               

              

               
              } 

      }
```

models:

```js
<?php
     //--Hay que crear un Name space del trabajo
      namespace App\Models;

      class Login extends Model{ //Mapeo de la tabla que se va usar
          protected $table='pruebamvc'; 
      }
```

Nota: en el archivo ".env" ya tiene la conexión de la DB. Y hago pruebas con "Thunder client" en la tabla de "pruebasmvc" y si lista registros. ¿Alguien tiene algún ejemplo para usar procedimientos almacenados / código que pueda seguir para implementarlo aquí?. Me comentan que Leaf es muy parecido a Laravel (No se nada de Laravel), pero, estoy tratando de aprender Leaf, porque me han dicho que es más "sencillo" que Laravel.

Gracias y saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En la documentación de leaf te habla de las [simple queriess](https://leafphp.dev/modules/db/#simple-queries), siguiendo esa sintaxis podriamos decir que:

```
$users = db()->query('CALL GetUsers()')->fetchAll();
```

Esto hablando que el procedimiento almacenado te devuelve valores.